# 「かみなりもん」 vs. 「らいもん」

Tags: readings, names

So I was watching something last year that involved a visit to 浅草神社.  Along the way there were conversations over what was the preferred way to read the name for the temple—either using the kun readings (あさくさじんじゃ) or on readings (せんそうじ).

The next bit struck me as a bit odd, though, when they got on the topic of the temple's 雷門.  I'd always assumed that it was straightforward: らいもん.  As it turns out though, it appears that the proper name for it is a mixed kun-on reading of かみなりもん instead.  Is there any particular reason for this?

Picture of the gate in question, for reference:

[image: image of the かみなりもん]

Comment: I'd always assumed that it was straightforward: らいもん >>> 実は私もです。。。

Comment: 1) あさくさじんじゃ and せんそうじ are two different things and they both exist.  2) Never heard らいもん.

Comment: @非回答者 [イナズマイレブンの雷門(らいもん)](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%82%BA%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AC%E3%83%96%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BB%E5%A0%B4%E4%BA%BA%E7%89%A9#.E9.9B.B7.E9.96.80.EF.BC.88.E3.82.89.E3.81.84.E3.82.82.E3.82.93.EF.BC.89.E4.B8.AD.E5.AD.A6.E6.A0.A1) のせいかな・・・スマソ！

Comment: 浅草にあるのになんで[浅草寺]{あさくさでら}じゃないんだろう・・・。ちなみに『「しみずじ」/「かわはらちょう」はどこですか？』と聞かれたとき、私は「 [清水寺]{きよみずでら}」と「[河原町]{かわらまち}」のことだと気付きませんでした。

Comment: @Chocolate せやから、寺と神社が隣同士に並んでるので、「浅草」の読み方を敢えて音と訓に分けてるのでは？それぞれ別の宗教の建物やし。地名や建物名、つまり固有名詞にあんまりルールを期待しても裏切られるだけでっせ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%B7%E9%96%80) article on Wikipedia, the name 雷門 first appeared in senryū (川柳) poetry of Edo period but it's not clear how it came to be used.

It's also interesting that the official name of the gate is full on-reading 風{ふう}雷{らい}神{じん}門{もん} and it comes from the two statues of Shinto gods 風神{ふうじん} and 雷神{らいじん} which stand inside the gate. The official name is written at the back of the lantern.

Comment: [風門]{かぜもん}はないんだぁ・・・　風神さんかわいそう・・